# Membership How to show current password

Tags: c#, membership

Is it possible to view current password? (Not to change)

I can not find any way on the Internet how to do it.

Comment: Use [MembershipUser.GetPassword()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x0c6sfa(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: google is your friend... my friend  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x0c6sfa(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is almost always a bad idea. Passwords should be hashed so they cannot be returned.

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a valid reason to return the password in plain text, but [MembershipUser.GetPassword()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x0c6sfa(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you are looking for

However, please see this note on that page:

> Returning a password in clear text using e-mail is not recommended for sites that require a high level of security. For high-security sites, it is recommended that you return passwords using encryption, such as SSL.